# Feedback form details to be get by an Email in asp.net (C#)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, facebook-c#-sdk, email-client, user-feedback

I have an feedback form , which is having detailed fields like
1. Name ,
2. Email ,
3. Profession ,
4. country ,
5. Comments ,
I want all these details to be get in my email account when any guest gives his/her feedback ... these details should be email me in my email id on submit event.

Please provide me some suggestion and code to do this in asp.net C#

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=send+email+asp.net

Answer (score 2):

So lets say that on your ASP.NET form you have something like the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" /> 
..
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSendFeedback" OnClick="btnClick" Text="Send Feedback"/>
```

Then in the code-behind, handle the feedback button click:

```
protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    message.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);

    // this should be replaced with your address 

    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("youremailaddress@foo.bar.com"));

    message.Subject = "feedback";

    // this is the email content, eg comments, profession, country, etc
    message.Body = "Name: " + txtName.Text;  // add more fields...


    // finaly send the email:
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Send(message);

}
```

Also make sure you set up the web.config, like so (or something similar)

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="test@foo.com">
        <network host="yousmtpserver" port="25" userName="username" password="password" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

For more info, have a look at this:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One you have your form controls setup, you just have to build the email body and subject then send it to you.

**UPDATE**

Something like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" multiline="true" runat="server" />
```

Then on your form submit postback method, something like this to build up the email body:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("You have an email from " + txtName.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Their email is: " + txtEmail.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Comments: " + txtComments.Text);
```

Then set the `sb.ToString()` as your email body.

Here is an example that walks you through some of that process - http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/68369

Comment: i have created my body and structure , but is it possible to take all these fields in my email id ??? i means these 5 fields which i have mentioned ???? is it possible to take all these details ????

Comment: what do you mean take all these fields in my email id?  I don't know what you mean by that. Does the update help?